# Django redirect to an swf

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to redirect to a swf file because I need to embedd that in a fb:swf which wants its absolute path. When I handle the swf in url's somehow it doesn't work.

In url.py

```
(r'^flash/','lastproject.yofacebook.flashtest.flash'),
```

In flahstest.flash

```
def flash(request):
return render_to_response('as3.swf')
```

I want to open the swf on this url

```
http://testapp.varheroes.com/flash/
```

the fb:swf

```
<fb:swf 
    swfbgcolor="ffffff"  
    swfsrc='http://testapp.varheroes.com/flash/'
    width='620' height='530' />
```

The error I get

```
'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-6: invalid data
```

Comment: http:\\testapp.varheroes.com\flash\ ? You mean forward / slashes?

Comment: What's the MIME type you are returning with your response? Looks like it might be defaulting to test/html. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render_to_response` is used to render a template and send it as a response. I don't think your swf file is a template, so you should just return it directly:

```
return HttpResponse(open('as3.swf'))
```

But really you shouldn't be sending that file through Django at all, it should be served by whatever is serving the rest of your static files (CSS, JS etc).

Comment: The thing is Django handle all my url's I just need to pass the swf's address to fb:swf  ( wouldn't open('as3.swf')) open a new window?

Comment: opening new window has nothing to do with HttpResponse, it is a browser action. Daniel is right - you should not be serving binary files like that, use apache nginx or whichever web server you are using to do static serving.

Comment: If my Django is serving all the url's of a certain prefix. Can I actually run away with static serving and bypass django url's?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep your swf file in the static directory and add a url pattern to redirect to your file eg:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    ...
    (r'^flash/', redirect_to, {'url': settings.STATIC_URL + 'as3.swf'}),
    ...
)
```

This redirects for example, /flash/ to STATIC_URL + as3.swf (eg: /static/as3.swf)
as3.swf shall be in your static directory.